# how do i search for certain word in a website?

Tags: web-crawlers, web-development, analytics

Is there any way to search within a website without manually checking out every link?

Suppose there is some website www.somewebsite.com and I want to search for a word in all of the pages www.somewebsite.com/1, www.somewebsite.com/2, and so on. Is there any way to do it without actually browsing through each and every page?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about searching some particular website rather than about running your own website.

Comment: `site:www.somewebsite.com word`